COPY FILES command taking very long time and doesn't actually copy
When I run this script in Snowflake:
COPY FILES INTO @az_uksdistrib/
FROM @az_uksdistrib/Archived
FILES = ('RFPT.9439.005589.DAT')

To 'un-archive' a file and place it back in the root of the stage, the operation takes around one minute, and although it completes successfully, the file does not actually copy over. When run on multiple files over a cursor, it takes around one minute per file.
The location @az_uksdistrib/Archived does have around 100,000 small DAT files (< 5MB) which I thought might be a part of the issue, but there are no timeout errors or anything like that.
EDIT - I re-ran the query with DETAILED_OUTPUT set to TRUE, but the only output in the results pane was Query produced no results.

Figured it out. Needed a slash at the end of the destination path:
COPY FILES INTO @az_uksdistrib/
FROM @az_uksdistrib/Archived/
FILES = ('RFPT.9439.005589.DAT')

It still takes a minute to copy the file but I assume that's because of the large number of files in the source location.

normally it is best if you have a "growning source of data" to put data in yyyy/mm/dd/hour structure, so you can then load from "more recent sub-folders" verse have the storage layer list "all files" every time you do a load. Again, if you are doing incremental loads.
